# MySQL compression options?

Tags: mysql

Are there any options to set regarding the MySQL table compression, other than:

```
KEY_BLOCK_SIZE

innodb_compression_level
innodb_compression_failure_threshold_pct
innodb_compression_pad_pct_max
```

Is it possible to exclude all blobs from the compression? Also, is it possible to replace the compression algorithm with something else?